# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.setHeader(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: scala, sbt

I had written a library and published it as a jar. Other applications used my library and everything was great.

Now the other application upgraded their dependencies. and now when they run. the application crashes when it calls my library. It seems that the application now depends on netty 4.1.8 whereas my library depended on a third party library which used an older version. Now when building the other application, sbt evicts my netty version with the newer one. The newer netty version does not have the method on which my code depends upon.

Thus the exception

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.setHeader(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V"
com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.construct(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:693) 
com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.buildRequest(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:650) 
com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener$Builder.build(NettyConnectListener.java:144) 
com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1070) 
com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:935) 
com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:499) 
dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.apply(execution.scala:47) 
dispatch.Http.apply(execution.scala:12) 
dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.apply(execution.scala:42) 
dispatch.Http.apply(execution.scala:12) 
scalaxb.DispatchHttpClients$DispatchHttpClient$class.request(httpclients_dispatch.scala:21) 
scalaxb.DispatchHttpClients$$anon$1.request(httpclients_dispatch.scala:6) 
scalaxb.SoapClients$SoapClient$class.soapRequest(soap12.scala:41) 
scalaxb.SoapClients$$anon$1.soapRequest(soap12.scala:23) scalaxb.SoapClients$SoapClient$class.requestResponse(soap12.scala:60) 
scalaxb.SoapClients$$anon$1.requestResponse(soap12.scala:23)
```

I am already using the latest version of the 3rd party library (scalaxb) which depends on old netty.

This is really killing because my library is holding back the entire upgrade process of the application.

Comment: maybe consider shading the older version of the dependency, https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much you can do about this, aside from telling that application's maintainers that using your library requires that specific version of netty, and is not compatible with newer versions. They have to either downgrade back or replace you library with something else.